How do I fill in the Circles detected using Hough transform?
using edge detection
using hough detection
I'm using Hough circle detection to detect a circle over a binary optic cup region.
Using the code below, I can fill in the circle but the lines of canny edge detection shows up inside the filled image. How do I fix that?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data, color
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

# Read the image
cimage = cv2.imread("cupcluster.jpg")

# Convert the image to grayscale
image = cv2.cvtColor(cimage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Perform edge detection using Canny
edges = canny(image, sigma=10, low_threshold=5, high_threshold=50)

# Detect circles using Hough Circle Transform
hough_radii = np.arange(78, 100, 2)
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)
accums, cy, cx, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii, total_num_peaks=1)

# Create an RGB image from the grayscale image
image_rgb = color.gray2rgb(image)

# Iterate over each pixel in the image
for y in range(image.shape[0]):
    for x in range(image.shape[1]):
        # Check if the pixel is inside any of the detected circles
        inside_circle = False
        for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
            if (x - center_x)**2 + (y - center_y)**2 <= radius**2:
                inside_circle = True
                break
        
        # If the pixel is inside a circle and is black, set it to white
        if inside_circle and image[y, x] == 0:
            image_rgb[y, x] = (255, 255, 255)
        
        # If the pixel is outside a circle and is white, set it to black
        elif not inside_circle and image[y, x] == 255:
            image_rgb[y, x] = (0, 0, 0)

# Display the result
plt.imshow(image_rgb)
plt.title('Image with Filled Circles')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()


This is the code I've used to transform and fill in.
and this is the input I'm getting filled Image with edge lines

it looks like you use wrong image. Maybe you should use original image image_rgb = cimage. OR you should duplicate gray image before you detect edges and later fill circle on duplicated image.

Pay attention on your checks of whether the pixel is inside a circle.
image[y, x] == 0 and image[y, x] == 255 conditions are redundant causing the bug, just remove them, i.e.
# If the pixel is inside a circle and is black, set it to white
if inside_circle:
    image_rgb[y, x] = (255, 255, 255)

# If the pixel is outside a circle and is white, set it to black
elif not inside_circle:
    image_rgb[y, x] = (0, 0, 0)

Since, in that conditions, your are comparing grayscale version of your original image, it is not necessary true that the pixel in that location will have 0 or 255 values.
Alternatively, to draw the circles you can use skimage built-in draw.disk function like this:
# Create an RGB blank image from the original image
image_rgb = np.zeros_like(cimage)

# Iterating over each detected circles and drawing them
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    rr, cc = disk((center_y, center_x), radius, shape=blank.shape)
    image_rgb[rr, cc] = 255

Or, if you want "to draw of your own", you can use numpy indexing, described here, like this:
# Create an RGB blank image from the original image
image_rgb = np.zeros_like(cimage)

# Iterating over each detected circles and drawing them
nrows, ncols = image.shape
row, col = np.ogrid[:nrows, :ncols]
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    mask = ((row - center_y)**2 + (col - center_x)**2 <= radius**2)
    image_rgb[mask] = 255

Below are full versions.
Version 1 (skimage.draw.disk):
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data, color
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage.draw import disk

# Read the image
cimage = cv2.imread("cupcluster.jpg")

# Convert the image to grayscale
image = cv2.cvtColor(cimage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Perform edge detection using Canny
edges = canny(image, sigma=10, low_threshold=5, high_threshold=50)

# Detect circles using Hough Circle Transform
hough_radii = np.arange(78, 100, 2)
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)
accums, cy, cx, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii, total_num_peaks=1)

# Create an RGB blank image from the original image
image_rgb = np.zeros_like(cimage)

# Iterating over each detected circles and drawing them
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    rr, cc = disk((center_y, center_x), radius, shape=blank.shape)
    image_rgb[rr, cc] = 255

# Display the result
plt.imshow(image_rgb)
plt.title('Image with Filled Circles')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

Version 2 (numpy indexing):
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data, color
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

# Read the image
cimage = cv2.imread("cupcluster.jpg")

# Convert the image to grayscale
image = cv2.cvtColor(cimage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Perform edge detection using Canny
edges = canny(image, sigma=10, low_threshold=5, high_threshold=50)

# Detect circles using Hough Circle Transform
hough_radii = np.arange(78, 100, 2)
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)
accums, cy, cx, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii, total_num_peaks=1)

# Create an RGB blank image from the original image
image_rgb = np.zeros_like(cimage)

# Iterating over each detected circles and drawing them
nrows, ncols = image.shape
row, col = np.ogrid[:nrows, :ncols]
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    mask = ((row - center_y)**2 + (col - center_x)**2 <= radius**2)
    image_rgb[mask] = 255

# Display the result
plt.imshow(image_rgb)
plt.title('Image with Filled Circles')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

Both versions have better time complexity.
